# How to sort arrays from the first character inputted by user followed by duplicates in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, .net, sorting, duplicates

i've been working on this

```
Public Sub Main()
        Dim str as String
        str = Console.ReadLine()
        str = str.ToLower()
        str = str.Replace(" ","")
        Dim mySort as Char() = str.ToCharArray()
        
        System.Array.Sort(mySort)

        For Each value As String In mySort
            Console.Write(value)
        Next
End Sub
```

if the input is **United States of America**

the result will be **aaacdeeefiimnorsstttu**
(it sorted alphabetically from a to z)

what I expect is **uniittteeedssaaaofmrc**
(sorted from the first character inputted from user followed by the duplicates (if there's any))

what should i do to have such expected result ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In reality your specification doesn't require any sorting but just a traversal of the elements (chars) of the string and the count of the elements of the same value present in the string

I would try with a [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) over the single characters and then a traversal in this way. During the iteration it is important to remove the characters found to not add them again to the resulting string

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim str As String
    str = Console.ReadLine()
    str = str.ToLower()
    str = str.Replace(" ", "")
    Dim myCharsCounter = str.GroupBy(Function(c) c).ToDictionary(Function(c) c.Key)
        
    Dim result As String
    For Each currentChar As Char In str
        If myCharsCounter.ContainsKey(currentChar) Then
           Dim charGroup = myCharsCounter(currentChar)  
           result &= New String(currentChar, charGroup.Count)
           myCharsCounter.Remove(currentChar)
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, friend of mine just also suggest to use while loop with condition, thanks again

Comment: Then post the solution that worked for you. In this way future visitors of this post with same or similar problem will find more choices and choose the best one.

Comment: I just did, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I tried running it on dotnetfiddle.net

```
Imports System
            
Public Module Module1
Public Sub Main()
    Dim txt,trm as String
    txt = Console.ReadLine()
    trm = txt.ToLower().trim().Replace(" ","")
    Dim chars as Char() = trm.ToCharArray()
    
    Dim i as integer = 0
    Dim j as integer = 0
    Dim temp as string = ""
    
    While (i < trm.Length)
        j = i + 1
        temp = temp + chars(i)
        
        While ( j < trm.Length)
        
            If (chars(i) = chars(j)) Then
                temp = temp + chars(j)
                chars(j)= " "
            End If
            
            j = j + 1
        End While
        
        i = i + 1
    End While
    
    temp = temp.Replace(" ","")
    Console.WriteLine(temp)
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).